# Outputting a comma separated txt file as a csv file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written a function in javascript that identifies a table in a HTML webpage, parses through the data and downloads it as comma separated values that retains the correct structure of the table. I was hoping there would be a simple way to download the tables as a csv file instead, making sure it keeps the correct structure (i.e. blank cells when present etc).

```
function downloadTableData(){
try{
var file_string = "";

var table_number = window.prompt("Table number:") - 1;
var column_names = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[table_number].children[0].children[0].children;

col_names = "";
for(var i=0; i<column_names.length; i++){
    col_names += column_names[i].innerText+",";
}
file_string += col_names += "\n";


var table_rows = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[table_number].children[1].children;
var extracted_rows = [];

for(var row_i=0; row_i<table_rows.length; row_i++){
    var row_vals = ""
    for(var col_i=0; col_i<table_rows[row_i].children.length; col_i++){
        row_vals += table_rows[row_i].children[col_i].innerText + ",";
        
    }
    file_string += row_vals+"\n";
    
    extracted_rows.push(row_vals);
}

var textInput = file_string;
alert('Table successfully detected');
var filename = window.prompt("Filename:");

var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href','data:text/plain;charset=utf-8, ' + encodeURIComponent(textInput));
element.setAttribute('download', filename);
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
} catch(err){
    alert('No table detected');
}
```

Comment: Stop using `.children[0].children[0].children` . Use the proper DOM methods like `Element.querySelector()`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Agreed.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I haven't looked into these before. Do you know if that will make the function more universal? At the minute I have several functions to use for different webpages as obviously the html hierarchy can differ

Comment: @ConorO'Neill added an answer for completeness. Notice the table ID and how to reusable DOM `EL("#tableTest")` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `blob` with type `text/csv`

```
let hiddenElement = document.createElement("a");
let csvData = new Blob([textInput], { type: "text/csv" });
let csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
element.href = csvUrl;
element.target = "_blank";
element.download = filename + ".csv";
element.click();
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. Unfortunately there is a new bug where when there is a comma in a cell that is meant to be there, it is splitting it into two cells. Hopefully I can figure out a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given this HTML Table sample:

```html
<table id="tableTest">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Anne</td>
            <td>Mar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

- Create some nifty reusable **DOM utility functions**
- Create a reusable `download()` **function**
- Create a `tableToCSV()` **function** that converts a common **HTML Table to CSV**

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const
    ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop),
    ELS = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel),
    EL = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);


// Task functions:

const
    download = (href, name = "unnamed") => {
        const EL_a = ELNew("a", { href, download: name });
        EL("body").append(EL_a);
        EL_a.click();
        EL_a.remove();
    };

const
    tableToCSV = (El_table, delimiter = ";") =>
        [...ELS("tr", El_table)].map(EL_tr => [...ELS("th,td", EL_tr)].map(EL_cell => EL_cell.textContent).join(delimiter)).join("\n");
```

to get your Table as CSV String use:

```js
const CSV = tableToCSV(EL("#tableTest"));
```

*Tip*: The default delimiter is `";"`. To change it to i.e a *Comma* use:

```js
const CSV = tableToCSV(EL("#tableTest"), ",");
```

finally to download it use your `download()` function.
Here are two examples:

1. using URI encoded **Base64 data href**

```js
download(
    "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFEFF" + encodeURIComponent(CSV),
    `whatever.csv`
);
```

2. using a Blob as **ObjectURL**

```js
download(
    URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([CSV], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8" })),
    `whatever.csv`
);
```

**Final output file:**

<sub>`whatever.csv`</sub>

```
Name;Surname
John;Doe
Anne;Mar
```

Comment: Thank you, going to spend the day making sure I understand what each bit of code is doing as I don't want to put it into my project without fully understanding it. I appreciate the help

Comment: @ConorO'Neill ask if anything is not clear. I can expand on the above code.

Comment: If I use the default delimiter will it solve the problem of creating a new column whenever there is a comma in one of the cells?

Comment: @ConorO'Neill exactly. use the default delimiter as explained in the answer

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if you could expand your answer any further. For the project the code is written within a chrome extension, for people with no code experience. The extension should download a table as csv with a click of the button. So entering the ID 'tableTest' will not work.

Comment: @ConorO'Neill *"download a table"*? What does that means? That's a too broad explanation. If going for an ID will not work, what do you think could work? You can always pass a HTMLTableElement. You don't necessarily have to use an ID. See for example how the StyleBot Chrome Extension works. That plugin allows you to select an element in the page. If that's not your use-case - you should explain your specific use case.

Comment: That is why I was using the getElementByTagName("table") as any table in the HTML would be called this. I was also thinking of adding a feature that would let the user click on the required table, the returned table could be the one the extension parsed.

Comment: At the minute it takes the user input "Table number" so they can select which table they would like if their are multiple on the page.

Comment: Okay I will try that, thank you

Comment: @ConorO'Neill That's a bad UI/UX... It would be nicer to allow to user to select with the mouse the desired Table! But anyways. Use instead `const CSV = tableToCSV(ELS("table")[table_number]);` Hopefully you'll understand now what the `EL` and `ELS` functions do.